# jQuery closest button after input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need the name of the next button from the input feald, the button can be in different positions(in table, in div after table, etc.). Like a find next in quelltext.

http://jsfiddle.net/LF6pK/

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Benutzer:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="Benutzername" name="Benutzername"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Passwort:</td>
        <td><input type="password" id="Passwort" name="Passwort"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="fr"><a href="#info" class="submit" onclick="login()">
                <button>Login</button>
            </a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
    $('input').keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which==13){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).closest('button').html());
        alert($(this).next('button').html());
    }
});
```

The alert is always undefined.

EDIT:
Sure i can give the button a unique id but i have 1 page with 10 buttons and each 10-20 inputs. So i hope a easy way to call always the next and dont give alle buttons a uniqe id and a seperate funktion to all inputs.

EDIT2:
I meen with the name the innerHTML of the button.

EDIT3:
The table is not always around the inputs.

EDIT4:
Better example http://jsfiddle.net/LF6pK/7/ and i prefer a dynamic like next button solution.

Comment: Need the html markup of the other positions it could be in..if it's completly random give it an `id | class | name`

Comment: What do you mean the "name" of the button? The button has no name in your example.

Comment: What is it that you're really trying to do? Are you trying to press the login button if the user presses **enter** in the input fields?

Comment: There is no way around this other than finding your parents siblings and then search through them for the button. You should rethink this design by not using tables but divs and a proper form.

Comment: you have an onclick of login() so why not just call that function rather than clicking the button? (which wouldn't call the function)  Also why have you wrpped a button in an anchor?

Comment: I updated my answer. Please read my explanations and see if it works for you, and if not, we can look for a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look, the problem is:

`.closest()` is used to call the closest PARENT.

`.next()` is used to call the next SIBLING, within the same parent of element.

How you should do it:

Use `.closest()` to call the CLOSEST PARENT that wraps the `<input>` AND the `<button>`.
As i can see in you HTML, the closest parent that wrap both is `<table>` tag. Then you have to use:

```
$('input').keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which==13){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).closest('table').find('button').text());
    }
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LF6pK/5/

**UPDATED:**

`var closest = $(this).closest(':has(button)')` will find the closest parent that has a button

`.parentsUntil(closest)` will call all parents until the closest parent that has a button

`.nextAll('button')` will call the buttons that comes only next each parents

`.first()` will filter the first one that comes next

jQuery:

```
$('input').keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which==13){
        var closest = $(this).closest(':has(button)')
        event.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).parentsUntil(closest).nextAll('button').first().text());
    }
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LF6pK/9/

**UPDATED [2]:**

```
$('input').keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which==13){
        var closest = $(this).closest(':has(button)')
        event.preventDefault();
        if($(this).parentsUntil(closest).nextAll('button').length >= 1){
            alert($(this).parentsUntil(closest).nextAll('button').first().text());
        } else {
            alert($(this).parentsUntil(closest).nextAll().find('button').first().text());
        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LF6pK/11/

Comment: What if button is under table?

Comment: And if no table around inputs?

Comment: Ok, i understand. now i updated my code, please, read my explanations and see if it works for you.

Comment: It will work for me, but if the button stay in a div it don't found him. If you can solve this its perfect way for enybody.

Comment: the definitive solution: http://jsfiddle.net/LF6pK/11/

Answer (score 0):

It will give you text of the button.

`$(this).parents().find('button').text()`

OR

`$(this).closest('table').find('button').text()`

Comment: this found all buttons not the closest

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that every button has same wrapper class (no need to be direct parent).

```
<table class='wrapper'>
   ...
   <tr>
       <td>
           <button></button>
       </td>
</table>

<div class='wrapper'>
    <input type='text'>
    <button></button>
</div>
```

Then you can access it by this:

```
$('input').keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which==13){

        var button = $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('button');

        event.preventDefault();
        alert(button.text());
        alert(button.text());
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

`alert($(this).offsetParent().find('button').html());`

http://jsfiddle.net/LF6pK/4/

Just position the element with relative or however you wish.

Have you considered using forms if you are just trying to perform an action on enter key press?

```
<form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Benutzer:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="Benutzername" name="Benutzername"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Passwort:</td>
        <td><input type="password" id="Passwort" name="Passwort"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="fr"><a href="#info" class="submit" onclick="login()"><button>Login</button></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<script>
$('body').on('submit','form',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do whatever with the inputs
});
</script>
```

Comment: _"the button can be in different positions(in table, in div **after table**, etc.)."_

Comment: Updated to use offsetParent() which may be more what you need http://api.jquery.com/offsetParent/

Comment: @ShaneMatthews that wouldn't work either: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/LF6pK/6/

Comment: It would at http://jsfiddle.net/LF6pK/8/ I mentioned you need to apply styling to the parent element (position:relative) will suffice.